# Apk and Jar Reflection

Tags: android, reflection

I'm develoing an android app that use reflection to read a project library that I made, I exported as APK and Jar extensions, I can read the apk but it fails with the jar it throws a ClassNotFoundException, so I don't know if am I missing something in the configuration when export the jar. I checked all the files in the project and mark it as library